# homotopy equivalent structure groups have h.e. classifying spaces (if $G\simeq H$ then $BG\simeq BH$)

Tags: homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

I believe there is a theorem like if $G$ and $H$ are homotopy equivalent topological groups, then $G$-bundles can have their structure group reduced to $H$ or equivalently (?) the classifying space $BG$ is homotopy equivalent to $BH$.

A more specific version of this fact is that real (complex) vector bundles can have their structure groups reduced from $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ ($GL_n(\mathbb{C})$) to $O(n)$ ($U(n)$), which is proved via linear algebra techniques like Gram-Schmidt or $QR$-decomposition.

But for the more general fact, I thought I once knew a purely homotopy-theoretic proof, using maybe fiber sequences or functoriality of the classifying space functor $B$. Can someone give the correct statement of the theorem and a nice homotopy-theoretic proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is true is that if $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism that is also a (weak) homotopy equivalence, then it induces a weak homotopy equivalence $BG\simeq BH$.  This is essentially immediate from the functoriality of $BG$ and the naturality of the isomorphisms $\pi_n(G)\cong \pi_{n+1}(BG)$ coming from the natural fiber sequence $G\to EG\to BG$: if $f:G\to H$ is a continuous homomorphism that induces isomorphisms $\pi_n(G)\to \pi_n(H)$, then $Bf:BG\to BH$ induces isomorphisms $\pi_{n+1}(BG)\to\pi_{n+1}(BH)$ since these groups are naturally isomorphic to $\pi_n(G)$ and $\pi_n(H)$.

Note that it is crucial that $f$ is not just a homotopy equivalence but also a homomorphism, since only homomorphisms induce maps $BG\to BH$.  Indeed, $BG$ and $BH$ may not be homotopy equivalent if $G$ and $H$ are merely homotopy equivalent.  For instance, $G$ and $H$ could be non-isomorphic discrete groups  of the same cardinality.

Comment: Yes that argument seems familiar and is almost certainly the thing i wanted to recall. Thank you.