# Existence of smooth global orthonormal frame on a Hilbert bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

This is basically a reference request, though I would also love to see the idea of a proof.

Suppose we are given a smooth Hilbert bundle $\pi: E \to X$ over a $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $X$ where the fibres are infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces.
There are some subtleties here since one needs to carefully define what is meant by smoothness and local trivialisations in infinitely many dimensions.
However, since I have not managed to find a good reference, I do not really care about these details at this point.

I have read multiple times that there always exists a global orthonormal frame thanks to the infinitely many dimensions, i.e a global section of the corresponding orthonormal frame bundle. But I am struggling to find any proofs of this fact, let alone a context with rigorous definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point here is Kuiper's theorem which says  that if $H$ is an infinite dim. real or complex separable Hilbert space then  $GL(H)$ is contractible in the norm topology.

The conclusion then follows from the theory of classifying spaces for (principal) bundles. Which tells you that $GL(H)$-bundles over $M$ up to isomorphism are in bijection with  homotopy classes of maps  $M \to B(GL(H))$ where $B(GL(H))$ is some topological space.

Since the inclusion $\{1\}\to GL(H)$ is a group homomorphism and by Kuiper's theorem is a homotopy equivalence then by  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341232/homotopy-equivalent-structure-groups-have-h-e-classifying-spaces-if-g-simeq-h) we see that $B(GL(H)) $ is homotopy equivalent to the classifying space of the trivial group which can be taken to be a point. Consequently there is only one homotopy class of maps $M \to B(GL(H))$ and thus only one iso. class of bundles (the trivial one).

A good reference are these notes by Dan Freed
https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2015/Notes/lecture12.pdf

----Another possible approach----
Instead of using classifying spaces we can use obstruction theory.
We want to construct a global section of a bundle $GL(H)\to P\to M$, we give $M$ the structure of a CW-complex, we choose a section over the $1$-skeleton and we try to extend it up to the $\mathrm{dim} M$-skeleton,
The obstructions to do so lie in $H^i(M, \pi_{i-1}GL(H))$, $i\geq 2$ but since by Kuiper $GL(H)$ is homotopy equivalent to a point $\pi_{i-1}GL(H) = (0)$ consequently all the obstruction vanish and we can construct a global section.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely more than I had been able to uncover myself. It goes a bit beyond my geometry knowledge though, so I will need to take some time to read up on this… Do you happen to know if there is a textbook covering this theorem? I would somehow have expected this to appear on page 50 in some book on infinite dimensional geometry…

Comment: I don't know of a textbook with this specific theorem. The proof of Kuiper's thm can be found in those notes mentioned in my answer. You can surely find classifying spaces or obstruction theory in several homotopy theory textbooks.